# NGINX status page reports on endpoints that no longer exist

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to get the status page to only show endpoints that are defined in the configuration?

We have a ton of data for endpoints that do not exist anymore.

It uses this module:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html

Answer (score 0):

In nginx.conf, You may enable below log format to trace the **endpoint upstream**

```
log_format main '"$time_local" $remote_addr '
               'request="$request" '
               'req_len=$request_length '
               'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
               'body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
               'referer=$http_referer '
               'upstm_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstm_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstm_resp_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstm_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstm_header_time=$upstream_header_time'
           'uagent=$http_user_agent';
```